# Merge 2 tables to fill in missing records in each - Access / SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have 2 tables with the same headers and same # of rows and columns - the only difference is that records in Table1 will be missing in Table2 and vice versa.
So if Table1 has 50% of the records then Table2 will have the other 50%.

I want to merge the 2 tables to get a full 1. I have tried JOINS, UNION ALL, UPDATE & INSERT INTO and none work

UNION ALL was close by gives an error for all column with 'multi-value fields' and UPDATE / INSERT INTO give an error because of the multi-value fields. INNER JOIN doesn't fill in the blanks at all.

Table 1

```
--ID--Header1--Header2--Header3 
   1    app1              org1
   2            lem2       
   3    app3              org3
   4            lem4
```

Table 2

```
--ID--Header1--Header2--Header3 
   1            lem1     
   2    app2              org2
   3            lem3       
   4    app4              org4
```

Comment: So, for the sample data you've provided, what are your expected results here? Perhaps you are after a `FULL OUTER JOIN`?

Comment: "UNION ALL was close by gives an error for all column with 'multi-value fields'" - what is the **exact error message**?

Comment: Larnu-expect result is for all the blanks to be filled in a single table - either in a new or existing table (Table1 or Table2)

Comment: Dai - it just said #ERROR in all the cells and didn't display any records

Comment: Are the "blanks" empty-strings or `NULL`s?

Comment: I think they are empty strings

Comment: @user15068397 Your table has **multi-valued fields** in it, which are a pain to deal with. You need to convert your columns to be scalars: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-or-delete-a-multivalued-field-7c2fd644-3771-48e4-b6dc-6de9bebbec31

Comment: Ohhh I see. Is there not a way to INSERT INTO: row 1 from Header1 in Table1 to (missing) row 1 from Header1 in Table2?

Comment: @user15068397 There is, but you need to fix your database design **first** - by changing the columns to scalar text columns, and not multi-value columns.

Answer (score 0):

For your sample data, you can just use `inner join`:

```
select t1.id, nz(t1.header1, t2.header1),
       nz(t1.header2, t2.header2),
       nz(t1.header3, t2.header3)
from table1 t1 inner join
     table2 t2
     on t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: `Nz( x, y )` only works on SQL that runs inside Access - when using JET or ACE externally you need to use `IIF( x IS NULL, y, x )`. (Just adding this tip to help anyone who needs to do this outside of Access).

Comment: This doesn't work. It says "The multi-valued field is not valid in nz(..)"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `table1` and `table2` don't have exactly-matching `ID` values, and you want the fixed data to appear in `table3` then you'll need to both `UNION` (not `UNION ALL`) and `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, like so:

```
INSERT INTO table3( ID, Header1, Header2, Header3 )
SELECT
    u.ID,
    u.Header1,
    u.Header2,
    u.Header3
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            t1.ID,
            IIF( ( t1.Header1 IS NULL OR LEN(t1.Header1) = 0 ) AND t2.Header1 IS NOT NULL, t2.Header1, t1.Header1 ) AS Header1,
            IIF( ( t1.Header2 IS NULL OR LEN(t1.Header2) = 0 ) AND t2.Header2 IS NOT NULL, t2.Header2, t1.Header2 ) AS Header2,
            IIF( ( t1.Header3 IS NULL OR LEN(t1.Header3) = 0 ) AND t2.Header3 IS NOT NULL, t2.Header3, t1.Header3 ) AS Header3
        FROM
            table1 AS t1
            LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
    
        UNION

        SELECT
            t2.ID,
            IIF( ( t2.Header1 IS NULL OR LEN(t2.Header1) = 0 ) AND t1.Header1 IS NOT NULL, t1.Header1, t2.Header1 ) AS Header1,
            IIF( ( t2.Header2 IS NULL OR LEN(t2.Header2) = 0 ) AND t1.Header2 IS NOT NULL, t1.Header2, t2.Header2 ) AS Header2,
            IIF( ( t2.Header3 IS NULL OR LEN(t2.Header3) = 0 ) AND t1.Header3 IS NOT NULL, t1.Header3, t2.Header3 ) AS Header3
        FROM
            table2 AS t2
            LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 AS t1 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
    ) AS u
```

Comment: Does IIF work in Access SQL? And the IDs (primary keys) for both tables are the exact same

Comment: @user15068397 `IIF` is supported by Access SQL both inside Access itself and in OLE-DB and ODBC through both JET and ACE.

Comment: @user15068397 My answer doesn't support Multi-Valued Fields either. You should change your table to _not_ use multi-valued fields first.

Comment: `OUTER JOIN` is not supported by Access SQL.

Comment: @Harun24HR _**Blast!**_ I curse the day Microsoft decided to let Access's SQL capabilities stagnate for **21 years**

Comment: @Harun24HR Waitasec, this document says that Access **does** support `LEFT JOIN` (which is the same as `LEFT OUTER JOIN`): https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/join-tables-and-queries-3f5838bd-24a0-4832-9bc1-07061a1478f6 - same here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/left-join-right-join-operations-ebb18b36-7976-4c6e-9ea1-c701e9f7f5fb

Comment: @Dai Yes Access supports only three types join (1) Inner Join. (2) Left Join. (3) Right Join.

Comment: @Harun24HR So what's your point then? Access does support `OUTER JOIN`